# Can I determine PHP array value deltas?

Tags: php

I have two multidimensional arrays that I need to determine the delta for each value.  I know the array_diff function only returns the difference in keys.  Is there a functon that will determine the delta for each set of values assuming the two arrays contain the same set of keys?

Example:

```
array_1(test1 => Array([key1] => 100, [key2] => 200 ) )

array_2(test1 => Array([key1] => 105, [key2] => 195 ) )
```

I would expect something like:

```
array_3(test1 => Array([key1] => 5, [key2] => -5 ) )
```

Are there any PHP methods to do this or am I on my own?

Comment: You're on your own, but that doesn't look too complex. (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers here suggested using foreach loop but I think creating anonymous function will be easier:

```
<?php
    $count_delta = create_function('$a,$b', 'return $a - $b;');

    $arr1 = array(100, 200);
    $arr2 = array(20, 180);

    $delta = array_map($count_delta, $arr1, $arr2);

    var_dump($delta);
```

Output will be:

```
array
  0 => int 80
  1 => int 20
```

Comment: +1 for `array_map()`. Usage of `create_function()` is a overly elegant IMO. But nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
$delta = array();

foreach( $array1 as $k=>$v )
{
  if( array_key_exists( $k, $array2 )
  {
    // preserve the key
    $delta[$k] = $array1[$k] - $array2[$k];

    // or don't
    $delta[] = $array1[$k] - $array2[$k];
  }
}

print_r($delta);
```

Comment: looks like I'm on my own. Thanks for the example!

Comment: What's about different array sizes?

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard The first array is the controller in this case. Note that we're explicitly looking up array 2's values by key. So, if there is anything not in $array2, nothing gets removed. If there is extra stuff, it doesn't get explicitly address.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function for that, but you can use this.

```
function delta_array($a, $b) {
    if (sizeof($a) != sizeof($b))
        return false;

    $arr = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < $c = sizeof($a); $i++)
        $arr[] = $b[$i] - $a[$i];

    return $arr;
}

$arr1 = array(100,200);
$arr2 = array(105,195);

$delta = delta_array($arr1, $arr2);

print_r($delta);
```

The above will return

```
Array
(
    [0] => -5
    [1] => 5
)
```